# What causes the crash of my crunch C extension for Python?

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to write a wrapper around [crunch](https://github.com/BinomialLLC/crunch) as C++.

The internal code seems to work fine,
but the returns don't work - all of them lead to a crash.
The code runs until the return and then crashs on it.

I added one dummy function to test if the problem lies in the return itself,
but that doesn't seem to be the case (see dummy function).
I also tried different return values,
including an empty return, but all of them lead to a crash too.

```cpp
static PyObject * dummy(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    return Py_BuildValue("{s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I}",
        "width", 0,
        "height", 0,
        "levels", 0,
        "faces", 0,
        "bytes_per_block", 0,
        "userdata0", 0,
        "userdata1", 0,
        "format", 0
    );
}

// texture info
static PyObject * get_texture_info(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    unsigned char * buf;
    UINT32 buf_length;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y*I", & buf, & buf_length)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    crnd::crn_texture_info texture_info;
    if (crnd::crnd_get_texture_info(buf, buf_length, & texture_info) == 0) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError, "Dividing %d by zero!", buf_length);
        return NULL;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "width: %d\n", texture_info.m_width);
    fprintf(stderr, "height: %d\n", texture_info.m_height);
    fprintf(stderr, "levels: %d\n", texture_info.m_levels);
    fprintf(stderr, "faces: %d\n", texture_info.m_faces);
    fprintf(stderr, "bytes_per_block: %d\n", texture_info.m_bytes_per_block);
    fprintf(stderr, "userdata0: %d\n", texture_info.m_userdata0);
    fprintf(stderr, "userdata1: %d\n", texture_info.m_userdata1);
    fprintf(stderr, "format: %d\n", texture_info.m_format);
    return Py_BuildValue("{s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I}",
        "width", texture_info.m_width,
        "height", texture_info.m_height,
        "levels", texture_info.m_levels,
        "faces", texture_info.m_faces,
        "bytes_per_block", texture_info.m_bytes_per_block,
        "userdata0", texture_info.m_userdata0,
        "userdata1", texture_info.m_userdata1,
        "format", texture_info.m_format
    );
}
```

```
D:\Projects\python_c\decrunch>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import crunch
>>> d = open("tests\\res\\dxt1.crn",'rb').read()
>>> crunch.dummy()
{'width': 0, 'height': 0, 'levels': 0, 'faces': 0, 'bytes_per_block': 0, 'userdata0': 0, 'userdata1': 0, 'format': 0}
>>> crunch.get_texture_info(d,len(d))
width: 128
height: 128
levels: 8
faces: 1
bytes_per_block: 8
userdata0: 0
userdata1: 0
format: 0

D:\Projects\python_c\decrunch>python
```

I would like to know how this problem can be fixed.

Complete code:

```js
#include <Python.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <Windows.h>
#else
    /* For System that are not Windows, we'll need to define these. */

    #if SIZEOF_SHORT == 2
        #define INT16 short
    #elif SIZEOF_INT == 2
        #define INT16 int
    #else
        #define INT16 short /* most things works just fine anyway... */
    #endif

    #if SIZEOF_SHORT == 4
        #define INT32 short
    #elif SIZEOF_INT == 4
        #define INT32 int
    #elif SIZEOF_LONG == 4
        #define INT32 long
    #else
        #error Cannot find required 32-bit integer type
    #endif

    #if SIZEOF_LONG == 8
        #define INT64 long
    #elif SIZEOF_LONG_LONG == 8
        #define INT64 long
    #endif

    #define INT8  signed char
    #define UINT8 unsigned char

    #define UINT16 unsigned INT16
    #define UINT32 unsigned INT32

#endif

/* assume IEEE; tweak if necessary (patches are welcome) */
#define FLOAT16 UINT16
#define FLOAT32 float
#define FLOAT64 double

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    typedef signed __int64       int64_t;
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__
    #define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 \
                       + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 \
                       + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
#endif

#include <string.h>

#if !defined(__APPLE__)
    #if defined(__FreeBSD__)
        #include <stdlib.h>
    #else
        #include <malloc.h>
    #endif
    #ifdef _WIN32
        #define malloc_usable_size _msize
    #endif
#endif
//#define CRND_HEADER_FILE_ONLY
#include "crunch/crn_decomp.h"


static PyObject * dummy(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    return Py_BuildValue("{s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I}",
        "width", 0,
        "height", 0,
        "levels", 0,
        "faces", 0,
        "bytes_per_block", 0,
        "userdata0", 0,
        "userdata1", 0,
        "format", 0
    );
}

// texture info
static PyObject * get_texture_info(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    unsigned char * buf;
    UINT32 buf_length;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y*I", & buf, & buf_length)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    crnd::crn_texture_info texture_info;
    if (crnd::crnd_get_texture_info(buf, buf_length, & texture_info) == 0) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError, "Dividing %d by zero!", buf_length);
        return NULL;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "width: %d\n", texture_info.m_width);
    fprintf(stderr, "height: %d\n", texture_info.m_height);
    fprintf(stderr, "levels: %d\n", texture_info.m_levels);
    fprintf(stderr, "faces: %d\n", texture_info.m_faces);
    fprintf(stderr, "bytes_per_block: %d\n", texture_info.m_bytes_per_block);
    fprintf(stderr, "userdata0: %d\n", texture_info.m_userdata0);
    fprintf(stderr, "userdata1: %d\n", texture_info.m_userdata1);
    fprintf(stderr, "format: %d\n", texture_info.m_format);
    return Py_BuildValue("{s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I}",
        "width", texture_info.m_width,
        "height", texture_info.m_height,
        "levels", texture_info.m_levels,
        "faces", texture_info.m_faces,
        "bytes_per_block", texture_info.m_bytes_per_block,
        "userdata0", texture_info.m_userdata0,
        "userdata1", texture_info.m_userdata1,
        "format", texture_info.m_format
    );
}

// level info
static PyObject * get_level_info(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    unsigned char * buf;
    UINT32 buf_length;
    UINT32 level_index;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y*II", & buf, & buf_length, & level_index)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    crnd::crn_level_info level_info;
    if (crnd::crnd_get_level_info(buf, buf_length, level_index, & level_info) == 0) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError, "Dividing %d by zero!", level_index);
        return NULL;
    }

    return Py_BuildValue("{s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I,s:I}",
        "width", level_info.m_width,
        "height", level_info.m_height,
        "faces", level_info.m_faces,
        "blocks_x", level_info.m_blocks_x,
        "blocks_y", level_info.m_blocks_y,
        "bytes_per_block", level_info.m_bytes_per_block,
        "format", level_info.m_format
    );
}

// unpack level
static PyObject * unpack_level(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    unsigned char * buf;
    UINT32 buf_length;
    UINT32 level_index;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y*II", & buf, & buf_length, & level_index)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    crnd::crn_level_info level_info;
    if (crnd::crnd_get_level_info(buf, buf_length, level_index, & level_info) == 0) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError, "Dividing %d by zero!", level_index);
        return NULL;
    }
    UINT32 bpb = level_info.m_bytes_per_block;

    crnd::crnd_unpack_context ctx;
    unsigned char * dst;
    void * ppDst[6];
    ppDst[0] = dst;
    UINT32 dst_length = bpb * level_info.m_blocks_x * level_info.m_blocks_y;

    ctx = crnd::crnd_unpack_begin(buf, buf_length);
    if (crnd::crnd_unpack_level(ctx, ppDst, dst_length, bpb, level_index) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unpack failed");
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError, "Dividing %d by zero!", dst_length);
        return NULL;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "pre ret");
    return Py_BuildValue("y*", dst);
}

// Exported methods are collected in a table
static struct PyMethodDef method_table[] = {
    {
        "dummy",
        (PyCFunction) dummy,
        METH_VARARGS,
        "Method docstring"
    },
    {
        "get_texture_info",
        (PyCFunction) get_texture_info,
        METH_VARARGS,
        "Method docstring"
    },
    {
        "get_level_info",
        (PyCFunction) get_level_info,
        METH_VARARGS,
        "Method docstring"
    },
    {
        "unpack_level",
        (PyCFunction) unpack_level,
        METH_VARARGS,
        "Method docstring"
    },
    {
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL
    } // Sentinel value ending the table
};

// A struct contains the definition of a module
static PyModuleDef crunch_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "crunch", // Module name
    "This is the module docstring",
    -1, // Optional size of the module state memory
    method_table,
    NULL, // Optional slot definitions
    NULL, // Optional traversal function
    NULL, // Optional clear function
    NULL // Optional module deallocation function
};

// The module init function
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_crunch(void) {
    return PyModule_Create( & crunch_module);
}
```

Comment: As a side comment, unlikely to solve the problem: it would be more Pythonic if you hadn't to pass `len(d)` additionally to `d`. Instead, your function should be able to derive the length from the string on its own.

Answer (score 1):

As https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html seems to indicate, `y*` is supposed to put data into a `Py_buffer`.

But what is that? https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html seems to explain it: it is a structure which has a bunch of useful fields. It remains tied to the original object. It must be released after use.

For you, that means that you have to do the following changes:

replace

```
unsigned char* buf;
```

with

```
Py_buffer buf;
```

and later

```
crnd::crnd_get_texture_info(buf, buf_length, &texture_info)
```

with

```
crnd::crnd_get_texture_info(buf.buf, buf_length, &texture_info)
```

or, in order to remove the need for your `len()` to be passed, maybe even better

```
crnd::crnd_get_texture_info(buf.buf, buf.len, &texture_info)
```

(but see the docs in order to learn whether you can use this `buf` in a contiguous way; there seem to be restrictions)

After use, you must release this buffer (`PyBuffer_Release()`).

If that seems to be too complicated, you should use the `y#` format which gives you two values: a `const char *` with your data and a `int` for the length.

Here, you would do

```
unsigned char* buf;
int buf_length; // or Py_ssize_t? See below.or not?
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "y#", &buf, &buf_length)) {
    return NULL;
}
```

and continue as you did.

Both versions derive the length from the object passed, so don't call it with `crunch.get_texture_info(d,len(d))`, but just with `crunch.get_texture_info(d)`.

Whether you have to define your `buf_length` as `int` or `Py_ssize_t` depends on whether you define `PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN` before including `Python.h` (as it says in a "Note" box somewhere in the docs). It says also: "It is best to always define `PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN`."

Disclaimer: These are only hints where you can proceed. I only have a vague idea how this actually works, but it seems to me that this could point into the right direction. In no way it is a directly usable solution.

Edit after your edit: This solution should be applied to all places where you currently parse your arguments with `y*`.